# How to prevent divs overlapping when window size changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, when the browser is maximized, everything falls into place as I intended. However, resizing the window make my divs overlap. I've tried many posts on here with similar problem but non of the other posts have helped so I am posting my own code.

CODE:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 for(var i = 1; i <= (32*16); i++){ 
  $('.container').append("<div class=\"squares\" ></div>");

 }
  var $sqrs = $('.squares');
  $sqrs.height("32px");
  $sqrs.width("32px");
  $sqrs.css("background", "#969696");
  $sqrs.css("float", "right");
  $sqrs.css("border-style", "solid");
  $sqrs.css("border-width", "0");
  
  $sqrs.on("mouseenter", function(){
   $(this).addClass("sqr1");
   $('.sqr1').css("background", "grey");
  });

 $('.item').click(function(){
  var numSqrs = parseFloat(prompt("How many squares do you want? (1-"));
 })

  

})
```

```css
body{
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

.wrap{
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

.top {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A3A3A3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  display: inline-flex;
 }
.bottom{ 
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 display: inline-flex;
 height: auto;
}
.container{
 height: 512px;
 width:1024px;
 position: fixed;
 left:20%;
 border: 1px solid #A3A3A3;
 top: 10%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 28px 36px 73px -13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 28px 36px 73px -13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 box-shadow:28px 36px 73px -13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 
}


#proj{
 margin-left: 150px;
}

 .head{
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 5px;
}

.parent{
 position: absolute;
 left: 30%;
 right: 50%;
 top: 20%;
}


.etc{
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
}

 #box{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 40px;
 }

 .Odin{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  
  font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 200;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: black;
 }

.menu{
 height: 100%;
 width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 8.2%;
 left: 0;
 float: left;
 margin:0;
 border: 1px solid #A3A3A3;
 border-top: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
   box-shadow: -1px 2px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
   display: inline-flex;
 }
 



.menu{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px;
}

.item{
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: inline-flex;
}

.item:hover{
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #A7A3A3;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: inline-flex;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.item1{
 float: right;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 13px;
  font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 200;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: black;
}

#trash{
 padding: 15px;
 margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Javascript/jQuery Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.0.min.js"></script>

  
 </head>
 <body> 
   <div class="wrap">
    <div class="top">
     <div id="box">
      <img class="head" src="images/odin_head.png"/>
     </div>
     <p class="Odin">The Odin Project</p>
     <p id="proj" class="Odin">Harsimran Mann's Etch-A-Sketch Project</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
     <div class="scd">
      <div class="menu"> 
       <div class="item">
        <img id="trash" src="images/grid-four-up-2x.png"/>
        <span class="item1"> New Grid </span>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <img id="trash" src="images/trash-2x.png"/>
        <span class="item1"> Clear </span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answers! 

But I fixed it by just changing all positions to relative.

Media queries I'm finding out is if I want to make it work on other devices. I'll give it a go too

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried media queries (like below) for that,

```
@media all and (max-width: 359px) and (min-width: 300px){ 
}
@media all and...
```

Answer (score -2):

Use media queries for making it responsive. If you find it difficult  try giving width and height in % instead of px.  % calculates height and width based on Window size.